# (focusout) behaves differently in firefox and chrome

Tags: angular

I was doing form validation on custom upload button by adding a red border if field is left empty.
Open the below demo link in both chrome and firefox. Click on the upload button, close the upload window and then click anywhere else to loose focus. The red border will be shown because it is empty and marked as touched. Now do the same thing on Chrome the red border will show as soon as you click the upload button which is what I dont want. I want behavior which I am getting on firefox.

DEMO https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m2hmua

```
<form [formGroup]="cForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <input type=text placeholder="name" formControlName="name"
  [ngClass]="{'err-border': (cForm.controls.name.errors?.required && cForm.controls.name.touched) || cForm.controls.name.errors?.required && submitted}" 
  >
  <br><br><br>
  <input type="button" type="file" formControlName="file" id="realInput" style="display: none">
  <button type="button" id="fakeBtn"
  [ngClass]="{'err-border': (cForm.controls.file.errors?.required && submitted) || (cForm.controls.file.errors?.required && cForm.controls.file.touched)}"
  (focusout)="focusFunction()"
  >Upload</button>
  <span id="text">No file selected</span>
  <br><br><br>
  <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

TS

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  cForm: FormGroup;
  submitted = false;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      file: ['', Validators.required]
    });
    var realInput = document.querySelector('#realInput');
    var fakeBtn = document.querySelector('#fakeBtn');
    var text = document.querySelector('#text');
    fakeBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
       // @ts-ignore
      realInput.click();

       })
       realInput.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
       // @ts-ignore
      if(realInput.value) {
         // @ts-ignore
        text.innerHTML = event.target.files[0].name;
      } else {
          text.innerHTML = "No file selected";
      }
       });
       fakeBtn.addEventListener("click", ()=> {
         this.submitted = false;
            // @ts-ignore
     document.querySelector('#realInput').value = "";
     this.cForm.controls.file.reset();
       // @ts-ignore
      document.querySelector('#text').innerHTML = "No file";
       });

  }
onSubmit() {
  this.submitted = true;
  if(this.cForm.invalid) {
    return;

  }
  console.log(this.cForm.value);
}

focusFunction(){
  //console.log('inside focus function, touched:',this.cForm.controls.file);
  this.cForm.controls.file.markAsTouched();
}

}
```

Comment: I see the same behavoiur both in FF an Chrome, the Chrome behaviour (which makes sense since the button is actually losing the focus).

Comment: Just so you know, Angular has it's own way of adding/removing event listeners and querying the DOM - you don't need to (and shouldn't) use `addEventListener` or `querySelector` - it can mess up change detection. You can add `(click)` directly to the template, and reference elements with `#` template references and `@ViewChild`